# R Studio in Scoupus Dataset(Bibtex) Error in names(Y) = c("Year ", "Articles") :

Tags: r, bibtex, scopus

I download datatset from the **scopus** dataset then try to read the dataset but an error occurred when trying show the summary of the dataset. I Downloaded **BIBTEX** file or (.bib).

All of the scopus dataset I downloaded in Bibtex is not working.
But then I tried in Web Of Science(WOS) the bibtex I download is working. I was able to finish all the details with no error in WOS.

Using bibliometrix package in Rstudio. I followed the steps in these link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bibliometrix/vignettes/bibliometrix-vignette.html

Code I Used:

```
Brunei <- readFiles("C://Users//starl//Desktop//Thesis(1-29-2018)//Brunei Darussalam//Scopus//1.R Studio//Brunei Darussalam Dataset(Scopus).bib")
BruneiPDF <- convert2df(Brunei, dbsource = "isi", format = "bibtex")
BruneiResults <- biblioAnalysis(BruneiPDF, sep = ";")
BruneiSummary=summary(object = BruneiResults, k = 10, pause = FALSE)
```

After entering these code:

```
BruneiSummary=summary(object = BruneiResults, k = 10, pause = FALSE)
```

These error Occured:
**Error in names(Y) = c("Year   ", "Articles") : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxjAh.png)**

The summary did not appear
[image: See the image to View the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error in your code depends on the following line:

```
BruneiPDF <- convert2df(Brunei, dbsource = "isi", format = "bibtex")
```

whether your data come from Scopus, you should write:

```
BruneiPDF <- convert2df(Brunei, dbsource = "scopus", format = "bibtex")
```

Comment: Thank You and it work. Appreciate the help. I can now continue my thesis